# Dot product on larger dimensional matrices

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

When I want to take the dot product of 2, 2D numpy matrix it works as intended

```py
>>> a = np.random.rand(20,10)
>>> b = np.random.rand(10,3)
>>> dotP = np.dot(a,b)
>>> np.shape(dotP)
(20, 3)
```

In my use case I want to do a similar operation but with higher dimension arrays. In below example the the first 2 dimensions of `a` (20 and 10) are equivalent to dims of a matrix in previous example. And the last 3 dimensions are introduced in here (6,5,4). Similarly in `b` matrix, 10 and 3 are from previous example and (6,5,4) is introduced. When I use the dot operation on the below example I get the following output.

```py
>>> a = np.random.rand(20,10,6,5,4)
>>> b = np.random.rand(10,6,5,4,3)
>>> dotP = np.dot(a,b)
>>> np.shape(dotP)
(20, 10, 6, 5, 10, 6, 5, 3)
```

What I want to achieve is a multiplication operation like the following:

```py
>>> dotP = np.dot(a,b)
>>> np.shape(dotP)
(20, 3, 6, 5, 4)
```

A possible solution is to do broadcasting in a for loop but I'm not sure if it's the best way to do it:

```py
dotP = []
for x in range(np.shape(b)[-1]):
    dotP.append(np.sum(a * b[:, :, :, :, x], axis=1).reshape((20,1,6,5,4)))
dotP = tuple(dotP)
dotP = np.hstack(dotP)
```

Comment: check out `np.matmul`. Read the docs carefully.

Answer (score 0):

The basic rule for `A.dot(B)` is that the last of `A` pairs with the 2nd to the last of `B`.

```
>>> a = np.random.rand(20,10,6,5,4)
>>> b = np.random.rand(10,6,5,4,3)
>>> dotP = np.dot(a,b)
>>> np.shape(dotP)
(20, 10, 6, 5, 10, 6, 5, 3)
```

Here the sum-of-products is on the shared `4`, with a kind of outer product on the other dimensions.  (20,10,6,5) and(10,6,4,3)

But you wanted the sum-of-products on the `10`, which is in the wrong place.

`matmul` handles 'batches' but with the same 'last of/2nd to last of rule'.  It should work then with a

```
(6,5,4,20,10) and (6,5,4,10,3) producing a (6,5,4,20,3)
```

where (6,5,4) is the shared batch dimensions.

```
In [43]: >>> a = np.random.rand(6,5,4,20,10)
    ...: >>> b = np.random.rand(6,5,4,10,3)
    ...: >>> dotP = np.dot(a,b)
    ...: >>> np.shape(dotP)
Out[43]: (6, 5, 4, 20, 6, 5, 4, 3)

In [44]: 
    ...: >>> dotP = np.matmul(a,b)
    ...: >>> np.shape(dotP)
Out[44]: (6, 5, 4, 20, 3)
```

We have more control over the dimensions with `einsum`:

```
In [46]:     >>> a = np.random.rand(20,10,6,5,4)
    ...:     >>> b = np.random.rand(10,6,5,4,3)
    ...:     >>> dotP = np.einsum('ijklm,jklmo->ioklm',a,b)
    ...:     >>> np.shape(dotP)
Out[46]: (20, 3, 6, 5, 4)
```